# php script redirect while sending pdf as attachement

Tags: php, wordpress, email, pdf

I am new in php programming and I have develop php script using TCPDF libary that takes data from pdf form fields and create flatten copy of that PDF using TCPDF , after that I use "AttachMailer.php" to send copies of PDF to client and customer, when user fill pdf form and click submit button flatten copy of that pdf is created in wp-content/uploads/pdf folder , and 
email code gets same copy fro wp-content/uploads/pdf folder and copy is forwarded to client and customer once copies are forwarded, it should show message "email has been sent.....email-address".

```
 // =============Email Form===============================
require_once(dirname(__FILE__)."/AttachMailer.php");
$mailer = new AttachMailer($Email, $Email, "Submitted Form Copy", "hello <b>Please Find the Attached Copy of form sumitted</b>");

$mailer->attachFile($fpath.$Contact_Name.'_'.$Email.$fID);

$mailer1 = new AttachMailer($Email,$CEmail, "CC for client Submitted Form ", "hello <b>Please Find the Attached Copy of form sumitted by </b>".$Contact_Name);

$mailer1->attachFile($fpath.$Contact_Name.'_'.$Email.$fID);

if($mailer->send()) {
   echo "Email has been sent to ".$Email."\n and" ; }
else{
   echo "error in email\n";
   exit();
}
if($mailer1->send()){
    echo "\nCC has been sent to ".$CEmail ; 
}
else{echo "\nerror in email CC was not sent to ".$CEmail;}!
```

the problem is that when user click submit button he/or she is redirected to home page (which i dont want)with executing  if and else statements in email code shown above

please help me how can I stop redirecting to home page.

you can see screenshot of redirected page from my dropbox

https://www.dropbox.com/s/t48rqemujn21q42/redirectpagescreenshot.png?dl=0

Comment: Please post the contents of AttachMailer.php  I don't see anything in the above code that is doing any "redirection."

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hxlme1hy902i55b/AttachMailer.php?dl=0

Comment: dear Milad thanks for your time I can send you pdf file and its corresponding php file for review